# How Overloading in Java Works?

Tags: java, oop, overloading, type-promotion

I fail to understand that why in the following code the output is "String Version". As everything is Derived from Object then why it matches to String version?

```
public class AQuestion
{
public void method(Object o)
{
    System.out.println("Object Verion");
}
public void method(String s)
{
    System.out.println("String Version");
}


  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
    AQuestion question = new AQuestion();
    question.method(null);
   }
}
```

Output:
    String Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java Code**

You have to pass an object for it to take object verion

```
public class TestProgram {


    public void method(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object Verion");
    }
    public void method(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("String Version");
    }


      public static void main(String args[])
       {
          TestProgram question = new TestProgram();
          question.method(question);
       }
    }
```